# Using java to create a dynamic rich:panelMenu

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, facelets

Hail

This attempt at using component libs to access a  `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`

```
<rich:panelMenu style="width:35%" mode="ajax"
        iconExpandedTopGroup="/img/logListIcon.png"
        iconCollapsedTopGroup="/img/logListIcon.png"
        iconCollapsedGroup="/img/logListFolderIconClosed.png"
        iconExpandedGroup="/img/logListFolderIconOpen.png"
        iconGroupTopPosition="left" iconItem="/img/logFileIcon.png">

        <!-- feed iteration -->
        <ui:repeat items="#{PanelMenu.panelNodes}" var="map">
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="#{map.key}"
                style="padding-left: 20px;">
                <ui:repeat items="${map.value}" var="entry">
                    <rich:panelMenuItem label="#{entry}"
                        action="#{PanelMenu.updateCurrent}">
                        <f:param name="current" value="#{entry}" />
                    </rich:panelMenuItem>
                </ui:repeat>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
    </rich:panelMenu>
    <rich:panel style="width:65%"
        bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
        <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
            <h:outputText value="#{PanelMenu.currentLog}" id="current" />
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:panel>
```

resulted in

```
|STDOUT| 2010-03-06 22:46:22,212 | ERROR | [http-8181-2]: Exception in the filter chain
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to org.richfaces.component.UIPanelMenuItem
```

so I think I need to get onto a resource to use

`FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();`

but as I'm fairly new to both java and jsf I need a bit  of help.  Can anyone suggest either the (probably small) java method to represent this intention or a really good resource specifically about programming dynamic stuff in RichFaces using java?

Naturally I've read the javadocs, but they don't give me a concrete example of some JSF, the associated backing bean java code, and a screen shot of the resulting component.

It may be asking a bit much, but I'm sure I'm not alone in thinking that with these three, I'd be able to understand the idea and apply it to many other component types in this family.

The RF demo doesn't include dynamic panelMenus or drop downs so I'm a bit stumped.

Thanks IA

**EDIT**
@BalusC: Thanks for the response, here is complete stack trace:

```
07-Mar-2010 19:05:52 com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to org.richfaces.component.UIPanelMenuItem
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelMenuRenderer.insertScript(PanelMenuRenderer.java:141)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.doEncodeEnd(HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.java:260)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.doEncodeEnd(HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.java:271)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:134)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:281)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TabRendererBase.encodeChildren(TabRendererBase.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:266)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:127)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:200)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:195)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:265)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:254)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:594)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
07-Mar-2010 19:05:52 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase doPhase
SEVERE: JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /index.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@30f369]
07-Mar-2010 19:05:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to org.richfaces.component.UIPanelMenuItem
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelMenuRenderer.insertScript(PanelMenuRenderer.java:141)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.doEncodeEnd(HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.java:260)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.doEncodeEnd(HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.java:271)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:134)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:281)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TabRendererBase.encodeChildren(TabRendererBase.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:266)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:127)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:200)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:195)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:265)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:254)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:594)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
|STDOUT| 2010-03-07 19:05:52,683 | ERROR | [http-8181-1]: Exception in the filter chain
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to org.richfaces.component.UIPanelMenuItem
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat cannot be cast to org.richfaces.component.UIPanelMenuItem
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelMenuRenderer.insertScript(PanelMenuRenderer.java:141)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.doEncodeEnd(HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.java:260)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.doEncodeEnd(HtmlPanelMenuRenderer.java:271)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:134)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:281)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TabRendererBase.encodeChildren(TabRendererBase.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:266)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:127)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:200)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:195)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:265)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:254)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:594)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace and the root cause if any?

Comment: @BalusC, thanks - I've added the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You apparently can't use `ui:repeat` as child of `rich:panelMenuGroup`. Try `c:forEach` so that it generates the `rich:panelMenuItem` components before the JSF component tree get built up. Also see [this example](http://seamframework.org/Community/DynamicMenuFromDatabase) of which was told that it works successfully (apart from another kind of problem).

Comment: I guess I get too close sometimes and can't see the wood for the trees.  I'd seen `c:forEach` earlier but the idea got lost among the other frustrations I have.  This worked fine once I'd sorted my beans out. Thanks BalusC.

Comment: BalusC, I've unticked this answer as the answer (but left the helpful vote) because I've come back to this problem which I thought I'd fixed.  Whereas using c:forEach tags works in a straightforward fashion, I've got another problem which I'd like to try and fix using pure java.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it was caused by the wrong delcaration of the jstl namespace.
The correct one is `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"`