# how to generate dynamic rich:panelMenu?

Tags: jsf

i have a problem to generate dynamic menu, i'm using JSF1.2. I tried the c:forEach with an arrayList to generate dynamic rich:panelMenu as BalusC advised in a related forum, but get Accessor never triggered in c:forEach. it ruined me a day. can anyone provide me a solution ?

```
 <c:forEach items="#{serviceListBean.services}" var="child">
              <rich:panelMenuItem mode="none">                  
                  <h:outputText value="#{child.serviceId}"></h:outputText>                                          
              </rich:panelMenuItem>
            </c:forEach>
```

what's wrong in this code? can anyone enlighten me?. For info, serviceListBean is request scoped bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible causes:

1. JSTL is not declared as taglib in JSP or Facelets. To confirm this, rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source*. Do you see `<c:forEach>` tag unparsed among the generated HTML? If you're using JSP, declare it as follows:

   ```
   <%@taglib prefic="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

   Or if you're using Facelets, declare it as follows in root element:

   ```
   xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
   ```

   On some servers like Tomcat, which doesn't ship with JSTL out the box, you would also need to install JSTL first, see also [this info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).
2. This piece of code is in turn been placed inside a JSF repeating component, like `<h:dataTable>` with a `var="serviceListBean"`. This is also not going to work. You would need to replace the JSF repeating component by `<c:forEach>` as well.

Comment: gr8 BalusC, solved with your first solution. I used wrong taglib uri as <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %> and now changed to <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>, got worked. Also someone cited in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394394/using-java-to-create-a-dynamic-richpanelmenu, he used http://java.sun.com/jstl/core, he got resolved. That assured me, no uri problem. So i never thought to change if BalusC remarked. Why this taglib uri confusion? where is documented?